# 'x' must be numeric R error when reading from file

Tags: r

I am trying to do Hartigan's diptest in R, however, I get the following error: 'x' must be numeric.

Apologies for such a basic question, but how do I ensure that the data that I load is numeric?

If I make up a set of values as follows (code below), the diptest works without problems:

```
library(diptest)                                                                                                      
x = c(1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9)    
hist(x)  
dip.test(x)
```

But for example, when the same values are saved in an Excel file/tab delimited .txt file (saved as one column of values), and imported into R, when I run the diptest the 'x' must be numeric error occurs.

```
x <- read.csv("x.csv") # comes back in as a data frame
hist(x)
dip.test(x)
```

Is there a way to check what format the imported data from an Excel/.txt file is in R, and subsequently change it to be numeric? Thanks again.

Any help will be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: `read.table` returns a `data.frame`. Some or all of its columns may be `numeric`. If `x` is such a column, then `hist(Dat$x)` would plot the histogram. But in your question you read `Dat` in and then use something else for `hist`. Doesn't make much sense. Post the output of `str(Dat)`, or of `dput(head(Dat, 20))`.

Comment: Apologies - I've edited my question (not enough space in comments) which have hopefully made it a bit clearer. I'll take a look thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what's happening. If you run the code that you know works, it's working because the data class is `numeric` as it should be. When you read it back in it's a data.frame, however. So you need to point to the numeric element of the data.frame:

```
library(diptest)                                                                                                      
x = c(1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9)

write.csv(x, "x.csv", row.names=F)
x <- read.csv("x.csv") # comes back in as a data frame

hist(x$x)

dip.test(x$x)
```

> ```
>   Hartigans' dip test for unimodality / multimodality
>
> data:  x$x
> D = 0.15217, p-value = 2.216e-05
> alternative hypothesis: non-unimodal, i.e., at least bimodal
> ```

If you were to save the file to a .RDS instead of .csv then you could avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could also check if your data frame contains any non-numeric characters as follows:

```
which(!grepl('^[0-9]',your_data_frame[[1]]))
```